# Chart.js - Date/Value Line Graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Any idea how to set a date on a Chart.js axis with a specific format and display the results as x,y values?

Currently, I'm sending the data separately, and the dates as labels, which is not what I need.

```
var x = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['2017-01-01 01:00:00','2017-01-01 02:00:00','2017-01-01 03:00:00','2017-01-01 04:00:00'....],
        datasets: [{ 
            data: [2,3,4,5....],
            label: "Africa",
            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
            fill: false
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Title'
        },
        bezierCurve: false
    }
});
```